# Android question: Can the tabhost be put in one of the tab?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have some information which I want to show in a cascading style, and would prefer to show it in tab way.

So my idea is to have a TabHost embedded into one tab of another parent TabHost.

I can have one layer of TabHost working, but when I tried to add another TabHost into one of the tab, it always given an error of:

**No resource found that matches the given name (at 'id' with value '@android:id/tabhostDiagnosis**

Anyone faced the same problem before?

Here is my code (removed the redundant part)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/Diagnosis">
                <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<!--  -->
                    <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:id="@android:id/tabhostDiagnosis"                        
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<!--                             -->
                            <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabsDiagnosis" 
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                            <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontentDiagnosis"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                            </FrameLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </TabHost>
                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I studied [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/TabHost.java) for TabHost.

It will reference the TabWidget (or FrameLayout) directly by the R.id.x.

```
mTabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.tabs);
```

This basically stops from having TabHost embedded into another one.

**So the answer is it will not work.**

Answer (score 0):

Winston is correct but ...

You can initiate another activity upon tab selection which can instantiate a new TabHost / TabWidget etc.